# How can I find my Yocto generated image? It was made using poky

Tags: linux, x86-64, yocto

I am creating an image for my x86-64 machine using `yocto`, but I cannot find the image generated by it. I have already explored the files (especially the build folder) but cannot find them.

Inside of **/poky** there are the following folders:

```
bitbake/  
contrib/        
meta/       
meta-selftest/  
meta-yocto-bsp/
build/    
documentation/  
meta-poky/  
meta-skeleton/  
scripts/
```

Inside of **/build** there are the following folders:

```
cache/  
conf/  
downloads/  
poky/  
sstate-cache/  
tmp/
```

Inside them are multiple files, however, I cannot find an image file that I can burn into a USB flash drive.

Comment: ./build/tmp/deploy/images/

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk, thanks a lot for your answer. Howerver, Rufus can't identify any of the files listed in this folder

Comment: bzImage ------
bzImage--5.10.21+git0+40a967b115_8c516ced69-r0-genericx86-64-20210503132523.bin ------
bzImage-genericx86-64.bin------
core-image-sato.env------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64-20210503132523.qemuboot.conf------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64-20210503132523.rootfs.manifest------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64-20210503132523.rootfs.wic------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64-20210503132523.rootfs.wic.bmap------

Comment: core-image-sato-genericx86-64-20210503132523.testdata.json------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64.manifest------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64.qemuboot.conf------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64.testdata.json------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64.wic------
core-image-sato-genericx86-64.wic.bmap------
core-image-sato-genericx86.wks------
grub-efi-bootx64.efi------
linuxx64.efi.stub------

Comment: Should I just copy them to a flashdrive?

Comment: you can `dd` the `wic` image.

Answer (score 2):

Your results are stored in `/build/tmp/deploy/images/...`

You can flash the wic images like:

```
sudo dd if=core-image-sato-genericx86-64.wic of=/dev/<urdevice> bs=4M status=progress
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated images can be found inside the build directory `build/tmp/deploy/images/`

Incase if you want to debug something you can look into the log files stored inside the tmp folder.

you can flash the wic image using a GUI tool like [balena etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)